# User with global admin, cannot view Application or Resource grp in Azure

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-resource-manager, azureportal

I`m a global administrator of my Azure Tenant and gave Global admin rights to others so they can manage the Azure Tenant.

However, they cant view any of the services already provisioned on Azure.

For Example, cannot view:

a) Resource group

b) Enterprise Applications

Please suggest what more shall I do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue may be caused by that you haven't been assigned a subscription.

Try to find it whether subscriptions in your Azure Account. (Put in "subscription" in search blank in Azure. )

If you don't have any subscription, try to connect the owner and  add your account as owner or else role . (Go to subscription > choose one subscription > Access control > Add ) The steps looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wayne, I`ll test and updat.e

Comment: @Jason ， Since it worked, please mark this answer to help more people, thanks!